# Excel averageifs multiple criteria on one range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I know how I can use `average(if(...` etc using an array, however I'm stuck on how to include other criteria in this

This is what I've got so far:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Avg_Range,Date,">=1/04/14",Date,"<01/05/14",Status, {"D","E","F","G","H","I","R"})
```

*(if date is in April, and status code is d or e or f or g or i or r)*

What would I need to do to make the "Status, {"D","E","F","G","H","I","R"}" part work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your `AVERAGEIFS` formula, with an array argument, is returning an array of values, some of which are `DIV/0`, and others might be single values, or represent the average of several values (if there are separate values with the same status).

In order to do what you want, the following formula should work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Date>=DATE(2015,4,1))*(Date<DATE(2015,5,1))*(Status={"D","E","F","G","H","I","R"})*Avg_Range)/
SUMPRODUCT((Date>=DATE(2015,4,1))*(Date<DATE(2015,5,1))*(Status={"D","E","F","G","H","I","R"}))
```

The first part SUMS the relevant entries; the second counts them and we divide.

Comment: Haven't you got your numerator and denominator the wrong way round? Also, I think the OP's year is 2014, not 2015. Perhaps a CSE version using AVERAGE(IF.. is slightly preferable, if not only for conciseness, e.g.: =AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(Date)=4,IF(YEAR(Date)=2014,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Status,{"D","E","F","G","H","I","R"},0)),Avg_Range))))

Comment: @XORLX Average = SUM/COUNT, so I don't think I have them switched.  (Also, when tested, gave the correct answer). And I did think the OP could adjust the date to whatever he really needed. And I think your CSE version will also work.

Comment: Apologies. When I copied your formula an hour ago it ended up with the SUM portion as the denominator! Must've miscopied.